# Delete a page in latex

Tags: titles, front-matter

I would like to a front page in latex. My problem is that when I do this, the first page is totally white:

```
\title{}
\author{}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{plain}
\includepdf[pages={1}]{forside.pdf}
```

Does anyone know how the first page which is totally white can be erased?
David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\maketitle` creates a cover page of its own with the specified parameters (everything that is in `\title`, `\author` and a few other commands). Try again without the `\maketitle` command.